# How do I remove focus from a button clicked in EmberJS?

Tags: events, ember.js

I have an ember controller and view and a button which can be clicked and handled by the controller.

```
App.SidebarController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        showComposer: function () {
            App.QueryComposerView.controller.toggleComposer();
        }
    }
});
```

And my template looks like so:

```
<div>
    <button {{action 'showComposer'}} {{bind-attr class="App.QueryComposerView.controller.composerVisible:btn-default:btn-danger"}}>Compose Query</button>
</div>
```

All works great, the button changes classes as one would expect, but I have a focus on the button once I click on it, and I can't seem to do something similar to `$(this).blur()` like I'm used to in jQuery events.

How do I tell the element to lose focus once it is clicked?

Comment: You need to use a view to access any event properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this, you can implement a component for having a button with an action that does the JQuery stuff and the send it to the router.